# Enable Spelling Correction with Microsoft Translator Text API to improve quality of translation?

Tags: microsoft-translator, google-translation-api, bing-translator-api

Users often make typos/spelling errors.  While translating end user provided text as input,  Microsoft Translator Text API seems to "fail" in these cases and returns unintelligible results.

When trying the same translation in Bing Web Search Widget, at least the web widget offers an alternative "did you mean" suggestion, and one can manually select the offered alternative and then see what that would translate to.

Is it possible in the Microsoft Translator Text API to ask it to also return possible alternative translations with confidence scores?  (Essentially also return the Did you mean phrase translation with the results so multiple translations can be displayed in our app)

Here is an example: In this case, the offered "Did you mean" corrects for the typo, and in fact translates properly.

Even though Bing/Google Web Widgets are shown in the screenshots, the Translator APIs in both cases show the same result.  We are showing the Web widget as that would be easier to repro.

[image]

[image]

For sake of comparison, Google Cloud Translation API does this automatically and offers the best plausible translation after apparently self-correcting for the typos.

See:

[image]

Other more egregious examples:

Even though Bing/Google Web Widgets are shown below, the Translator APIs in both cases show the same result.

Bing/Microsoft Translator

[image]

Google Translate/ Google Cloud Translator API
[image]

(At the moment we have to use the Microsoft Translator API and can not switch to Google)

Answer (score 0):

Does not seem possible. You might be able to use the Bing spell check API for this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/apis/bing-spell-check-api